# CSS shrink browser window, float white space

Tags: html, css

I am in the following situation:
I have a container that has display set to inline-block. So the width of the container depends on the content inside it.

Inside the container I have two divs floated left;both have fixed width;the divs float next to each other where the browser window width is bigger that the sum of the widths the two divs have.

But, and here comes my problem, when I shrink the browser window so that the two divs won't fit next to each other anymore, the second floated div goes under the first floated div (as it should, I am happy with this), but the width of the container does not modify, even though the second div isn't there anymore, the container still preserves the space for it. I would link the container to shrink as well to the width of the bigger floated div.

Any help would be apreciated. Thanks a lot!

```
.Container {
    position:absolute;
    top:180px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background: #DDD;
}
.Container span {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:0px;
    text-align:left;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    cursor:default;
    background: red;
}
.div1 {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    width:100px;
    background: coral;
}
.div2 {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    width:200px;
    background: #45dc2a;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="Container">
    <span>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div2"></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C4Hcm/

Comment: You need to show us your code if you want us to be able to help

Comment: you're using set widths, if you want it to shrink/grow, you need to use percentages.

Answer (score 3):

Two possible solutions:

1) use media queries so that when the browser gets to a certain size the css changes. So when the second div drops at that point you add a media query where the divs both fill the container. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

2) use percentages on your sizes instead of pixels - using pixels makes the divs stay a fixed size what ever happens to the browser using percentages makes the div x% of whatever width you have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I know I can do it with media queries but I kind of like to stay away from them because they require writing for every situation and I was looking for something more automatic. For example if the width of the floated divs is different on each page refresh, I would need another media query and I find it a bit messy.

Comment: As for the percentage idea, I can not use it because the container is inline-block so it doesn't have a defined width. If I set width x% on the elements inside they won't know to what width to set themeselves. It's funny that on old versions of IE, I get exactly the behaviour I want. It seems that modern browsers have changed the rule, and the width of the inline-block container stays the same when floats collapse.

Comment: change you css and html or use javascript then. Why is it inline block?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have mentioned the width for container as 100% so it tries to accomodate the available space. Also do a w3 validation of your code, a div tag cannot be inside a span tag.

Comment: The span is not trying to acomodate anything because it is set as inline-block so its width is set by its content. Even if I put text inside the span, instead of those divs, it still behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with a small jquery script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.container{
background: yellow;
width: 100%;
}
.container .secondContainer {
    text-align:left;
background: blue;
display: inline-block;
max-width: 300px;
}

.div1 {
width:100px;
background: coral;
float: left;
}
.div2 {
width:200px;
background: #45dc2a;
float: left;
}
</style>
<script>

 $(window).resize(function(){
if($(".container").width() >= "300"){
$(".div1,.div2").css("float", "left");
}else{
  $(".div1,.div2").css("float", "none");

}
});
</script>
```

and the body contains

```
<div class="container">
<div class="secondContainer">
    <div class="div1">This is a text container  </div>
    <div class="div2"> This is a text container This is a text container</div>
</div>
```